# How does Dredge work with drawing more than one card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

How does dredge work with drawing multiple cards at once? For example, let's say I cast [Windfall](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWindfall%5d) and discard three cards, a [Golgari Grave-Troll](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGolgari%20Grave-Troll%5d), and a [Stinkweed Imp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStinkweed%20Imp%5d). With the at least five cards I am drawing from Windfall, could I dredge two of the draws with the troll and the imp? If so, how exactly do I do that properly? Do I get to select which of the five draws I am dredging?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes and yes.  Yes you can dredge both cards, and yes you can select which of the five draws you are choosing to replace with a dredge.  More than that, though, when you draw cards, you do so one by one.  So you could in theory be like "I'm looking for a specific card.  Draw 1?  Not it.  Draw 2?  Not it.  Draw 3?  Ok that's what I want, I'll Dredge using my other 2 draws instead of drawing".

To do this "properly" in the most formal way, you would say "I'm drawing a card and replacing my draw with CARDNAME".  Then you return CARDNAME to your hand and mill that many cards.  If you would like to dredge multiple cards in 1 action, you can shortcut this by saying "I'm going to draw 2 cards, I'm going to replace those draws with dredging CARDNAME1 and CARDNAME2".  Then you return both of those cards to your hand and mill a number of cards equal to the sum of their Dredge numbers.

Relevant sections of Comprules:

> 121.2. Cards may only be drawn one at a time. If a player is instructed to draw multiple cards, that player performs that many individual card draws.
>
> 702.51a Dredge is a static ability that functions only while the card with dredge is in a player’s graveyard. “Dredge N” means “As long as you have at least N cards in your library, if you would draw a card, you may instead put N cards from the top of your library into your graveyard and return this card from your graveyard to your hand.”

Comment: Alright. Is it possible if I could get the rulings for this?

Comment: Updated answer.  I believe those should be sufficient to explain the rules?

Comment: Alrighty, rule 121.2 was the one I was curious in seeing. Tyvm for adding the rulings

Comment: I didn't want to add this to the answer because you didn't ask the question, but another corrolary of rule 121.2 is that if you draw multiple cards in 1 action and you dredge the first card and you mill another dredger as part of that dredge action, then you are allowed to dredge that dredger for your second draw.  As a concrete example, say you cast Divination and for the first draw you dredge a Golgari Gravetroll.  You mill 5 cards, plus a Stinkweed Imp.  Then you may dredge that Stinkweed Imp with the second draw from the same Divination.

Comment: That is definitely something I would wonder eventually and I am glad you added it in as a comment. Thanks!

Comment: I occasionally play Legacy Dredge (like once every 2 years to remind myself why I hate playing the deck, but I own all the cards so mise), so I know most of the common interactions with those cards.

Comment: So "Each player discards their hand" resolves before "then draws cards" takes effect?

Comment: @Accumulation: When resolving the effects on a card, do them in the order printed, from top to bottom.